# Rotating symbol layers based on attribute values and direction of connected services

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, symbology, utility-network

I'm working with ArcGIS Utility Network and I would like to rotate my taps to align with the direction of the service lines.

Here is an example of what they look like initially:
[image: Taps with no rotation angle generated]

As you can see, the taps are all rotated in a similar direction and all of the "Symbol rotation" angles are zero. I need an idea of how to use python to take the angle of the designated service line perpendicular to the point, calculate the angle of the line, and populate that within my symbol rotation field. I've seen a few posts similar to this, but the code has not worked very well for me.

The desired result looks a bit like this:

[image: Desired result]

The taps are pointing toward the services.

If using Python to script and obtain this value, what exact tool will determine the angle of each line?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a numeric field in your point dataset that holds the rotation value, you are not showing this, so that's the first step. You then set the marker rotation property to be that field so it gets its rotation from that field. Make sure its rotation style is geographic; this sets up the layer ready to rotate the markers correctly.

You then need to write some python code to populate that field, the key function is the Point method [angleAndDistanceTo](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/pointgeometry.htm#M2_GUID-5853F68B-6164-4FDA-81C9-C0DEF50F0830)() and you can do that to the next vertex in the polyline.

This of cause assumes your point is snapped to the end of the polyline and you'll have to deal with it being at the FROM end as well as the TO end if your network polylines are inconsistently digitised.